# Making a Slot Machine on iOS

Tags: iphone, ios4, ios5

Is there any hint that the spinning effect of images/patterns (on Slot Machine) can be implemented on iOS ?

What I can think of is to use animation of graphics of UIImageView.

Any better suggestion ?

Answer (score 2):

You can go with UIPickerView containing UIImageViews as elements, or check this [url](http://dev.doukasd.com/2011/04/infinite-scrolling-dial-control-for-ios/)

Answer (score 0):

What about a `UIPickerView` with custom views ?